# What object rotate(theta) rotates in this example?

Tags: processing

[In this example](http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/chapter-14/example-14-16/) I am confused about the use of rotate and translate, more specifically,

```
// The earth rotates around the sun
  pushMatrix();
  rotate(theta);
  translate(50,0);
  fill(50,200,255);
  ellipse(0,0,10,10);
```

What does `rotate(theta);` rotate? What is the relation of rotate and translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rotate and translate are acting on the current coordinate system.

i.e.  draw actions (rect(), ellipse(), etc...) will apply within a the current coordinate system. where rotate & translate will move the coordinate system.

prior to the block of code you supplied, the current point was translated to the center of the window in order to draw the sun.

pushMatrix() saves that position and then relative to the suns center, "everything" (the coordinate system) is rotated by theta, and "everything" is translated by (50,0) effectively moving the "current point" to the correct position to then draw the earth using ellipse(0,0,10,10).

Note you could probably omit the translate step and use ellipse(50,0,10,10) to get the same visual result, if it were not for the fact that the next code block is dependent on that translate to get the moon position correctly.

[Here is an interesting link which explains this in terms of "moving the graph paper"](http://processing.org/learning/transform2d/);